# Changing persistent colors for all app widgets in runtime by pressing the button

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I would like some advice from you if you have time.
I have created a class that will manage colors for certain widgets in most classes and in various types of widgets (stateless and stateful). Changing the value of AppPreferences.instance().themeIsDark (true / false) by pressing a button and using the setState () method unfortunately the colors change only on the current widget (current window). Is it possible to change the variable to change colors in all classes and widgets where they are used?

```
class AppTheme {
  AppTheme._();

  static Color myWhite() => AppPreferences.instance().themeIsDark! ? Color(0xFFFFFFFF) : Color(0xFF000000);

  static Color notWhite() => AppPreferences.instance().themeIsDark! ? Color(0xFFECF0F1) : Color(0xFF1A1A1A);

  static Color nearlyWhite() => AppPreferences.instance().themeIsDark! ? Color(0xFFFEFEFE) : Color(0xFF222222);

  static Color myGray1() => AppPreferences.instance().themeIsDark! ? Color(0xFFC1C1C1) : Color(0xFF333333);

  static Color myGray5() => AppPreferences.instance().themeIsDark! ? Color(0xFF767676) : Color(0xFF4F4F4F);

  static Color myGray2() => AppPreferences.instance().themeIsDark! ? Color(0xFF4F4F4F) : Color(0xFF767676);

  static Color myGray4() => AppPreferences.instance().themeIsDark! ? Color(0xFF333333) : Color(0xFFC1C1C1);

  static Color myGray3() => AppPreferences.instance().themeIsDark! ? Color(0xFF222222) : Color(0xFFFEFEFE);

  static Color myNotBlack() => AppPreferences.instance().themeIsDark! ? Color(0xFF1A1A1A) : Color(0xFFECF0F1);

  static Color myBlack() => AppPreferences.instance().themeIsDark! ? Color(0xFF000000) : Color(0xFFFFFFFF);
}
```

```
Switch(
      value: AppPreferences.instance().themeIsDark!,
      onChanged: (value) async {
      setState(()  {
         AppPreferences.instance().themeIsDark = value;                                       
         AppPrefFlutterStorage.saveAppPrefToFlutterStorage(AppPreferences.instance()); 
                 });
              },
      activeTrackColor: AppTheme.myBlue,
      activeColor: AppTheme.myGray1(),
      inactiveThumbColor: AppTheme.myGray1(),
   ),
```

AppPreferences.instance (). ThemeIsDark I keep it locally in FlutterSecureStorage and after restarting the application the colors change their values everywhere but in runtime unfortunately not.
I would like to change the persistent colors throughout the application by pressing a button. I don't know if it's possible. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you could accomplish themes/skins. The "most official" way would be to create material [ThemeData](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html) objects and pass them to your [MaterialApp()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html).

However, if you have assets or attributes that need to change but aren't included in ThemeData, for example background images, you could use a `class MyThemeManager` singleton that is a [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider), and `watch` MyThemeManager in your widgets' build() methods.

```
class MyTheme {
  Color edgeColor;
  String bgImageName;
  //...etc...
}

//ChangeNotifier will tell "watching" widgets when theme has changed
class MyThemeManager with ChangeNotifier {
  
  //This Map will hold available themes.
  Map<String,MyTheme> myThemes;
  //This will hold the current theme
  MyTheme myCurrentTheme;

  //Create MyThemeManager as a singleton
  static final MyThemeManager _instance = MyThemeManager._pConstructor();
  MyThemeManager._pConstructor() {
     //Create your different themes here in myThemes Map
     myCurrentTheme = myThemes["default"]; //name of your default theme
  }
  factory MyThemeManager() {
    return _instance;
  }

  //The method to change your themes
  void changeTheme(string themeName) {
     myCurrentTheme = myThemes[themeName];
     notifyListeners(); //tell watching widgets to redraw     
  }
}
```

Then in a stateful or stateless widget's build():

```
build(BuildContext context) {

   //This will "watch" MyThemeManager and when it calls
   //notifyListeners() this widget will redraw
   MyTheme theme = context.watch<MyThemeManager>().myCurrentTheme;
   
   return Container(
     color: theme.edgeColor,
     ...
   );    
}
```

when you want to change your theme:

```
MyThemeManager().changeTheme("lightTheme");
```

And any watching widget will update

In your root widget you pass to runApp(), wrap the top child with Provider() or MultiProvider():

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => MyThemeManager(), lazy: false),
        //you can put more providers here if you have them 
      ],
      child: MyMaterialApp()
    );
  }
}
```